# How can I check multiple line for one customer with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id | START_DATE | END_DATE   | id_customer
----------------------------------------
1  | 01/05/2016 | 31/05/2016 | 1234
2  | 10/10/2016 | 11/11/2016 | 1234
3  | 11/11/2016 | 15/05/2017 | 1234
4  | 31/12/2016 | 31/06/2017 | 1234
```

I want select if a START_DATE equal a END_DATE.

For example:

11/11/2016 line id 3 don't equal 31/05/2016 line id 1

11/11/2016 line id 3 equal 11/11/2016 line id 2

11/11/2016 line id 3  don't equal 15/05/2017 line id 3

11/11/2016 line id 3  don't equal 31/06/2017 line id 4

I have try a request like this

```
SELECT id_cutsomer,START_DATE, END_DATE
FROM TABLE
WHERE START_DATE IN (
    SELECT END_DATE FROM DATA_BEAUTY_BOX
)
```

I want this result:

```
 START_DATE | END_DATE   | id_customer
------------------------------------
 11/11/2016 | 11/11/2016 | 1234
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a self `join` should suffice

```
select  t1.START_DATE, t2.END_DATE, t1.ID_CUSTOMER
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.START_DATE = t2.END_DATE
```

If you don't want to mix dates of different customers, you will have to make the `join` condition stricter

```
select  t1.START_DATE, t2.END_DATE, t1.ID_CUSTOMER
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.START_DATE = t2.END_DATE and
        t1.ID_CUSTOMER = t2.ID_CUSTOMER
```

Comment: I think you'll have to add the customer ID in the mix and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

I would join the tables on Customer ID and then Add the (Start Date = End Date) condition on the WHERE clause.  (although you could do them both on the JOIN)

```
SELECT t1.START_DATE, t2.END_Date, t1.id_customer 
FROM MyTable t1     
    INNER JOIN MyTable t2   
        ON t1.id_customer = t2.id_customer
WHERE t1.START_DATE = t2.END_Date
```